# Google map API script not loading some time causing reference exception and stop another body on load processes

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, onload

I am using google map API on front page of my website, to initialize a function onload of the google map, I was doing this

```
<script>
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize_map);
</script>
```

but the problem what I thought with this was when the browser sometimes was not able to load the script this piece of code cause error onload and stops other functions from running.
To solve this problem I did this

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?region=IN&libraries=places&key=MY_API_KEY&callback=setMap" async></script>

function setMap(){

         google.maps.event.addDomListener(window,'load',initialize_map);

    }
```

provided function name in callback parameter of Javascript means the function will run only after the script is loaded completely, but still, the same problem of

```
Reference Error: google is not defined
```

is coming, and now I am not even able to know why it is stopping other onload function to run, In the previous case may be it was coming because  I have written the function in the body itself, but now even after declaring it in the function causing the same problem.please tell me how to make it work and please provide some tips if there are to load google map in some better way.

Comment: your code works fine for me on my domain with my API_KEY, as long as I wrap the javascript in a script tag - in your case, is `function setMap(){` a global function, or are you wrapping that in something that you haven't shown in the question?

Comment: actually, the function is wrapped in Javascript and in general, it is working fine for me also, but in 1 out of 10 cases when someone opens the page for the first time, maybe because at that time the script is not cached in the browser and because of internet connection the browser is not able to load the script then this problem happens.

Comment: unlikely, since `setMap` is called by the script that's loaded

Comment: Now I am trying to solve the problem by placing the script tag at top of page and placing all map related javascript on the page itself instead of separate JS file, maybe then it be able to load it at the first time.

Comment: ahhh, yes, you didn't say it was in a separate file :p